# How to Store Secret Keys in Android

Tags: java, android, security, oauth

```
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preference",0);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("clientId","MY_CLIENT_ID");
    editor.putString("clientSecret","MY_SECRET_KEY");

    editor.commit();
```

In the above code, I am hard coding both client id and secret key in my android app. Since, These two are very sensitive data, How can I store them in a secured way ?

Comment: "secured way" makes no sense: what level of security? SharedPreferences are private to the application. Use encryption if you need more security or something.

Answer (score 0):

You store it in a secure way in `SharedPreferences` by calling the SharedPreferences file in private mode:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences( "Your_file_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
```

Only your application can access this. There is no way for other applications or the user to see the contents of the preferences, unless you implement code to show it, of course!

You're doing just fine, although you should use `MODE_PRIVATE` instead of `0`, because in the future, the value of MODE_PRIVATE **might** change, which would make a hard `0` behave different from `MODE_PRIVATE`.